# Camera access by 2 programs at the sametime

Tags: kernel

In operating systems like Windows and Android, just a single program may access a camera peripheral at any given time.

Are there any other operating systems that allow two or more programs access to a camera simultaneously?

Alternatively, can any operating system be modified to make that happen?

ROM based on linux like kali linux can be installed in android phone. In this situation, exe files other than apk can also run in android too. Then can an app and the other exe file use camera simultaneously? cuz they are different so i think they dont interrupt each other when it comes to using camera

Comment: this might be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/165727/is-it-possible-for-two-processes-to-access-the-webcam-at-the-same-time

Comment: Thank you. but i am saying about physical use of camera. Not about virtual camera . anyway
I appreciate your reply!

Comment: `As we all know` ... no,  we do not all know ... please do not make assumptions about people's knowledge